# Draw a circle (not shaded) with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I am trying to draw a circle very similar to the orbital patterns on [this](http://planetoweb.net/app/) website.  I would like to use Three.js instead of pure WebGL.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Three.js r50 added `CircleGeometry`. It can be seen (albeit with a face) in the [WebGL Geometries example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometries).

The first vertex in the geometry is created at the center of the circle (in r84, see [CircleGeometry.js line 71](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r84/src/geometries/CircleGeometry.js#L71), in r65, see [CircleGeometry.js line 18](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/r65/src/extras/geometries/CircleGeometry.js#L18)), which is nifty if you are going for that "full Pac-Man" or "uninformative pie chart" look. Oh, and it appears to be necessary if you are going to use any material aside from `LineBasicMaterial` / `LineDashedMaterial`.

I've verified that the following code works in both r60 & r65:

```js
var radius   = 100,
    segments = 64,
    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } ),
    geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( radius, segments );

// Remove center vertex
geometry.vertices.shift();

// Non closed circle with one open segment:
scene.add( new THREE.Line( geometry, material ) );

// To get a closed circle use LineLoop instead (see also @jackrugile his comment):
scene.add( new THREE.LineLoop( geometry, material ) );
```

PS: The "docs" now include a nice `CircleGeometry` interactive example: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/geometries/CircleGeometry

Comment: When using this method with `THREE.Line`, there was a gap between the first and last vertices. To get a fully closed circle, use `THREE.LineLoop` instead. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/objects/LineLoop

Comment: ^ Doesn't quite work anymore. See my answer for an update: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312034/1599699

Comment: This code is deprecated for THREE.REVISION = "150". Please see my code https://stackoverflow.com/a/75658328/5175935 below for a solution

Answer (score 13):

The API changed slightly in newer versions of threejs.

```
var segmentCount = 32,
    radius = 100,
    geometry = new THREE.Geometry(),
    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF });

for (var i = 0; i <= segmentCount; i++) {
    var theta = (i / segmentCount) * Math.PI * 2;
    geometry.vertices.push(
        new THREE.Vector3(
            Math.cos(theta) * radius,
            Math.sin(theta) * radius,
            0));            
}

scene.add(new THREE.Line(geometry, material));
```

Modify `segmentCount` to make the circle smoother or more jagged as needed by your scene. 32 segments will be quite smooth for small circles. For orbits such as those on the site you link you, you may want to have a few hundred.

Modify the order of the three components within the `Vector3` constructor to choose the orientation of the circle. As given here, the circle will be aligned to the x/y plane.

Comment: this is not working when i take THREE.Mesh...any idea?

Answer (score 5):

I had to do this lol:

```
function createCircle() {
    let circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1.0, 30.0);
    circleGeometry.vertices.splice(0, 1); //<= This.
    return new THREE.LineLoop(circleGeometry,
        new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 'blue' }));
}
let circle = createCircle();
```

**Reason:** Otherwise, it doesn't draw a "pure" circle, there's a line coming from the center to the rim of the circle, **even if you use LineLoop instead of Line**. Splicing (removing) the first vertex from the array is a hack but seems to do the trick. :)

(Note that apparently, according to [mrienstra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21742175/1599699), "Oh, and it appears to be necessary if you are going to use any material aside from LineBasicMaterial / LineDashedMaterial.")

---

If you want thickness, though, [you're screwed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638883/thickness-of-lines-using-three-linebasicmaterial) (["Due to limitations of the OpenGL Core Profile with the WebGL renderer on most platforms linewidth will always be 1 regardless of the set value."](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/LineBasicMaterial))... Unless you use: https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine

Code example for that is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312721/1599699

Comment: This code is deprecated for THREE.REVISION = "150". Please see my code https://stackoverflow.com/a/75657438/5175935 below for a solution.

Answer (score 4):

I used code that Mr.doob references in [this github post](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/98).

```
var resolution = 100;
var amplitude = 100;
var size = 360 / resolution;

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xFFFFFF, opacity: 1.0} );
for(var i = 0; i <= resolution; i++) {
    var segment = ( i * size ) * Math.PI / 180;
    geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vertex( new THREE.Vector3( Math.cos( segment ) * amplitude, 0, Math.sin( segment ) * amplitude ) ) );         
}

var line = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
scene.add(line);
```

Comment: this is not working when i take
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
any idea..?

Answer (score 3):

This example is in the Three.js documentation:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000ff
});

var radius = 5;
var segments = 32; //<-- Increase or decrease for more resolution I guess

var circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( radius, segments );              
var circle = new THREE.Mesh( circleGeometry, material );
scene.add( circle );
```

Answer (score 2):

I had some issues getting the other answers to work here -- in particular, `CircleGeometry` had an extra point at the center of the circle, and I didn't like the hack of trying to remove that vertex.

[`EllipseCurve`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/extras/curves/EllipseCurve) does what I wanted (verified in r135):

```
const curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
  0.0, 0.0,            // Center x, y
  10.0, 10.0,          // x radius, y radius
  0.0, 2.0 * Math.PI,  // Start angle, stop angle
);

const pts = curve.getSpacedPoints(256);
const geo = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(pts);

const mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 0xFF00FF });
const circle = new THREE.LineLoop(geo, mat);
scene.add(circle);
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, I dunno when they added it - but TorusGeometry should do the job...
[image: THREE TorusGeometry]
[THREE TorusGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/TorusGeometry)

```
const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry( 10, 3, 16, 100 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
const torus = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( torus );
```

Dunno, but I think it shouldn't be (much) more expensive than the line thingy and it's a buffer geometry and you may adjust size and material etc...

Answer (score 2):

The [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61312034/5175935) from Andrew's answer is deprecated for THREE.REVISION = "150". I see an error message:

*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'splice')*

for the

```
circleGeometry.vertices.splice(0, 1);
```

line.

Please see my edited code below for a solution:

```
function createCircle() {
    const circleGeometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(1.0, 30);

    // Remove center vertex
    const itemSize = 3;
    circleGeometry.setAttribute( 'position',
        new THREE.BufferAttribute(
                circleGeometry.attributes.position.array.slice( itemSize,
                    circleGeometry.attributes.position.array.length - itemSize
                ), itemSize
            )
    );
    circleGeometry.index = null;

    return new THREE.LineLoop(circleGeometry,
        new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({ color: 'blue' }));
}
const circle = createCircle();
```

Answer (score 1):

See the three.js sample http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_lines_colors.html to see how to draw colored lines.

A circle like the ones you cite is drawn as a large # of little straight segments. (Actually, the ones you show may be ellipses)

Answer (score 1):

```
var getStuffDashCircle2 = function () {

var segment = 100, radius = 100;

var lineGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var vertArray = lineGeometry.vertices;
var angle = 2 * Math.PI / segment;
for (var i = 0; i < segment; i++) {
    var x = radius * Math.cos(angle * i);
    var y = radius * Math.sin(angle * i);
    vertArray.push(new THREE.Vector3(x, y, 0));
}
lineGeometry.computeLineDistances();
var lineMaterial = new THREE.LineDashedMaterial({ color: 0x00cc00, dashSize: 4, gapSize: 2 });
var circle = new THREE.Line(lineGeometry, lineMaterial);

circle.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
circle.position.y = cylinderParam.trackHeight+20;
return   circle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing a 3D object with a fixed thickness (which becomes apparent when you zoom in) you can just make a fixed thickness circle that stays a thin line, which is very nice for a UI overlay, just like OP example link

`absarc()` and `setFromPoints()` very useful here.

```
//Draws an orbit at 0,0 with given distance

let pts = new THREE.Path().absarc(0, 0, orbitDist, 0, Math.PI * 2).getPoints(90);
let g = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(pts);
let m = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ffff, transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 } );
g.rotateX( - Math.PI / 2);
let l = new THREE.Line(g, m);
    
scene.add( l );
```

As it makes an arc in 2D, you can move it in 3D if you wish with `.position.set(x,y,z)`, or, I add it to the scene here at the 3D origin anyway (0,0,0). I rotated due to my 3D perspective camera angle.

Answer (score 0):

The [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21742175/5175935) from mrienstra's answer is deprecated for THREE.REVISION = "150". I see an error message:

*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'shift')*

for the

```
geometry.vertices.shift();
```

line.

Please see my edited code below for a solution:

```
const radius   = 100,
    segments = 64,
    material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0x0000ff } ),
    geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry( radius, segments );
                                            
// Remove center vertex
const itemSize = 3;
geometry.setAttribute( 'position',
    new THREE.BufferAttribute(
            geometry.attributes.position.array.slice( itemSize,
                geometry.attributes.position.array.length - itemSize
            ), itemSize
        )
);
geometry.index = null;
                                            
// Non closed circle with one open segment:
scene.add( new THREE.Line( geometry, material ) );
                                            
// To get a closed circle use LineLoop instead (see also @jackrugile his comment):
scene.add( new THREE.LineLoop( geometry, material ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

The "brute force" methods (using for, cos, sin) now (R149) need to use BufferGeometry instead of Geometry:
But I like the "absarc" approach of Jammo (without g.rotateX()).

```
function docircle(r, segs, color) {
  let x,y,angle,avertices=[],geometry,material,lines;
  for (let i=0; i<segs; i+=1 ) {
    angle = i/segs*Math.PI*2;
    x = r*Math.cos(angle); y = r*Math.sin(angle);
    avertices.push(x,y,0);
  }
  geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
  geometry.setAttribute('position', new THREE.Float32BufferAttribute(avertices, 3));
  material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color:color } );
  lines = new THREE.LineLoop(geometry, material);
  scene.add(lines);
}
```