# three.js intersecting CircleGeometry works when using THREE.Line, but not when using THREE.Mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js

See following fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1jmws2bp/

If you move the mouse over the line or the circle, it should change color to white (works for me, locally, in jsfiddle sometimes there is a bit of an offset, not entirely sure why).

Problem is, that if you change Line 22: to `var circle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)` the circle is filled out (as intended), but if you now hover it now, it won't update color.

Why is that? If I manually add this:
`scene.children[0].material.color.setHex(0xff0000);`

it does work. So somehow it looks to me that with a Mesh the RayCaster does not see the intersection. (Verified by adding this line
`alert("intersection");` after `if (intersects.length > 0)` no alert if I use `Mesh` instead of `Line`)

Comment: if you want to intersect mesh of circle, then remove the line `geometry.vertices.shift();` from the `newCircle()` function

Comment: @prisoner849 Thanks, I wonder though... I added this because of this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756112/draw-a-circle-not-shaded-with-three-js. What I wonder about is: With `new THREE.Line` it works with or without the shift, but with Mesh it does not, when the shift is present. Why is that? Also, if you add an answer I will gladly accept it!

Comment: I made an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to intersect mesh of circle, then remove the line `geometry.vertices.shift();` from the `newCircle()` function.

When you call `.shift()`, you remove the first element from the array of vertices. Such "shifted" array in a geometry is acceptable for `THREE.Line()` as it needs vertices only, but not acceptable for `THREE.Mesh()`, which needs vertices and faces based on vertices.

And also, if you want to use `THREE.Mesh()` then change the material from `THREE.LineBasicMaterial()` to `THREE.MeshBasicMaterial()`.