# How can I control line width using the THREE.js createMultiMaterialObject function?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm experimenting with the **createMultiMaterialObject** function in THREE.js to create shaded objects that also display a wireframe. The problem is the lines appear broken & don't seem to respond to the **wireframeLinewidth** parameter.

My materials are defined as follows:

```
var mat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xd02000, transparent: true, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending } )
var blackLines = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x000000, wireframe: true, wireframeLinewidth: 4 } );
```

And the object is here:

```
 var object = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 4, 4, 4 ), materials );
                object.position.set( -100, 150, 0 );
                scene.add( object );
```

But this produces this result:[image: Bad WireFrame on MultiMaterial]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine. Are you running Windows? If so, it is possibly an ANGLE issue, in which case the line width cannot be changed. See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638883/thickness-of-lines-using-three-linebasicmaterial).

If you are unable to increase the line width, a work-around in your case is to make the wireframe mesh just a bit larger than the solid mesh, like so:

```
object.children[ 1 ].scale.multiplyScalar( 1.01 );
```

If you do that, there will be no more broken lines and it will be beautiful. :-)

three.js r.55

Comment: Yes, I'm running Windows 8 64-bit. Thanks for the tip.