# THREE.js ignoring linewidth for a BufferGeometry + LineBasicMaterial in a THREE.Line?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've created a minimal test case for my question: http://pastebin.com/TPXFgxLj

The expected behavior is a red set of lines, with a line width of 19.
The actual behavior is a red set of lines, with a linewidth of (apparently) 1.

What am I doing wrong? I've tested the opacity option of the material, and it is followed (changing it to 1 does produce a more opaque set of lines). The color also seems to be followed correctly, so why isn't the linewidth?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug indeed and it just got fixed in r56 dev branch.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Windows? If so, it is possibly an ANGLE issue, in which case the line width cannot be changed. See this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638883/thickness-of-lines-using-three-linebasicmaterial).

EDIT: In the cases of `THREE.BufferGeometry`, the inability to set `material.linewidth` in `THREE.LineBasicMaterial` was a bug. It has been fixed in the current r56dev branch.

three.js r.55

Comment: Hi, sorry for not mentioning it. This is OS X 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion), running Chrome 24.0. Does my example render correctly for you on Linux?

Comment: Note that if I just use a Geometry, this works as expected. The testcase which does increase line width is at: http://pastebin.com/fcm5cnNd

This does show a thick red line, on the same platform and OS as above.

Comment: I'm on OSX, too, and unfortunatley, I am now not able to test for a few days. Sorry. You might get more suport by posting a live example at jsfiddle.net. This makes it easier for people to help you. In the mean time, pinging @mrdoob ...