# Workaround for lack of line width on Windows when using Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm trying to draw a rotating 3D coordinate system using Three.js. I want the axes to have some thickness, which so far I have accomplished using LineBasicMaterial's linewidth parameter.

The following code works for me since I am not on Windows:

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();                                              
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.   innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );                                                           

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
    document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

    var triad = new THREE.Geometry();
    triad.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0,  0,  0 ) ); 
    triad.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3( 10,  0,  0 ) );
    triad.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0,  0,  0 ) );
    triad.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0, 10,  0 ) );
    triad.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0,  0,  0 ) );
    triad.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(  0,  0, 10 ) );

    var line_mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({'linewidth': 3});

    var frame = new THREE.Line(triad, line_mat, THREE.LinePieces);
    scene.add( frame );                       
    camera.position.z = 40;                        

    function render() {                    
        requestAnimationFrame(render);             
        frame.rotation.x += 0.1;            
        frame.rotation.y += 0.02;             
        renderer.render(scene, camera);                            
    }                                                                           
    render();
```

Unfortunately, there is a limitation on linewidth on Windows due to the ANGLE library, see this question: [Thickness of lines using THREE.LineBasicMaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638883/thickness-of-lines-using-three-linebasicmaterial)

What can I use as a workaround so that this displays correctly on Windows?

Comment: You could create CylinderGeometry with the specific length and orientate the cylinders. For smoother stuff, you could try setting up splines and extruding along those splines like in this example: 
http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines

Also you can figure stuff out with your own approach and creating your own Geometry, depending on your needs but I think setting up a few cylinders for your coordinate system should be ok? 

Also you can tell Firefox for example to use native OpenGL drivers and then having linewidth under windows but this is slower in most cases...

Answer (score 2):

I got workaround for the width of the line. I created a new method and passed the coordinates where line is to be drawn. Then in your method , draw multiple lines around the coordinates. Here is the code :

```
function drawLine(lineMaterial, x1, y1 , z1, x2, y2, z2, thickness){
    for (i = 0; i < thickness * 2; i++) {  // multiplied it by 2 to be more granule pixels
        var routerLine1Geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        routerLine1Geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x1, y1+i/4, z1));//divided it by 4 to be more granule pixels 

        routerLine1Geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x2, y2+i/4, z2)  );
        var routerLine1 = new THREE.Line( routerLine1Geometry, lineMaterial );
        scene.add(routerLine1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < thickness * 2; i++) { 
        var routerLine1Geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
        routerLine1Geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x1, y1-i/4, z1)  );  // 
        routerLine1Geometry.vertices.push( new THREE.Vector3(x2, y2-i/4, z2)  );
        var routerLine1 = new THREE.Line( routerLine1Geometry, lineMaterial );
        scene.add(routerLine1);
    }
}
```

Let me know if this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

To run WebGL with native gl you have to install the OpenGL in your windows machine.

You have these options below:

1. Google Chrome "solution": "run chrome with the `--use-gl=desktop` command-line argument. As you can see in http://nuclear.mutantstargoat.com/webgl/
2. Firefox "solution": "Just type in navigation bar `about:config` and search for preference `webgl.prefer-native-gl` and set to `true`. As you can see in "http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=2090351&start=15

Answer (score 1):

By using Angle the rendering is actually handled by DirectX. Switching to native gl can even lead to performance increase (depending on the OpenGL performance of your graphics card).

You can check the current "under the hood" WebGL settings of your browser [using this website here](http://www.browserleaks.com/webgl) .
It also shows you if your browser is currently using angle for WebGL.

You can also check [this website](http://www.geeks3d.com/20130611/webgl-how-to-enable-native-opengl-in-your-browser-windows/) for detailed explanation of how to switch to native gl.

Answer (score 0):

There are many possibilities -- I have used cylinders.  This routine gives flat lines in the xy plane:

```
function doline(x1, y1, x2, y2, z, w, color) { // draw a "line"
  // scene.add(doline(x1, y1, x2, y2, z, w, 0xrrggbb)) call like this
  if (typeof color == "undefined") color = 0xffffff;
  color = new THREE.Color( color );
  var d = Math.sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1)); // length
  var geometry = new THREE.Geometry;
  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color:color, side:THREE.DoubleSide });
  var u1=w*.35, u2=w*.5, v1=0, v2=w*.15, v3=w*.5, v4=w*.85, v5=w; // rounded ends
  fan(geometry, 0, -w/2, z, [[-u1, v2],[-u2, v3],[-u1, v4],[0, v5],[ d, v5]]); // left
  fan(geometry, d,  w/2, z, [[ u1,-v2],[ u2,-v3],[ u1,-v4],[0,-v5],[-d,-v5]]); // right
  geometry.rotateZ(Math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1)); // rotate first
  geometry.translate(x1,y1,0);               // then translate
  var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  return mesh;
  function fan(geom, x0, y0, z0, pts) { // add vertices and faces in xy plane based on x0, y0, z0
    // pts must be 2 or more points relative to x0,y0 [[x1,y1],[x2,y2],..]
    geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x0, y0, z0)); // base point
    var i0 = geom.vertices.length-1; // add to vertices
    for (var i1=0; i1<pts.length; i1+=1) { // 
      geom.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(x0+pts[i1][0], y0+pts[i1][1], z0));
      if (i1 > 0) geom.faces.push(new THREE.Face3( i0, i0+i1, i0+i1+1) );
    }
  }
}
```