# Expand or make a THREE.LineSegments thicker

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on visualizing paths of lines in Three.JS and have successfully added a bunch of lines to the scene with the correct vertices, and material that I want but the lines are hard to see. Is there a way to convert a line segment into a tube of sorts without having to start from scratch and change the type of geometry I'm using?

I may not be using the correct terminology but I basically want to turn a generated `THREE.LineSegments()` into a thicker line in 3D. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
var geo = new THREE.BufferGeometry();
geo.addAttribute('position', new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(2*numTravelVertices), 3));
var travelVertices = geo.attributes.position.array;
var vertIndex = 0;
this.set('travelVertices', travelVertices);

<add vertex indicies for points on the path>

geo.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({color: parseInt(this.get('travelColor')), transparent: false});
var lineSegments = new THREE.LineSegments(geo, new THREE.MultiMaterial([mat]));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Workaround for lack of line width on Windows when using Three.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067461/workaround-for-lack-of-line-width-on-windows-when-using-three-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw thick lines by setting the `LineBasicMaterial` `linewidth` parameter:

```
material.linewidth = 4; // default is 1
```

This currently does not work on some Windows platforms. So an alternate solution is to use the thrid-party class [THREE.MeshLine](https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine), which renders thick lines by drawing a strip of triangles.

You can use `THREE.TubeGeometry`, but that would not be as performant as `MeshLine`.

three.js r.82

Comment: I voted to close the question as duplicate, but this answer is pretty useful. Your working regarding `linewidth` support, "except on some Windows platforms", surprised me. Are there any Windows browsers left that do not run on Angle/DirectX (i.e. thus supporting linewidth)? I usually describe WebGL linewidth as "generally not supported".