# Threejs: why is wireframe thickness not adjusting for me?

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am unable to create thick wireframes. Using the following code:

```
new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {
    color: new THREE.Color( 'rgb(100,100,100)' ),
    emissive: new THREE.Color( 'rgb(23,23,23)' ),
    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
    wireframeLinewidth: 10,
    wireframe: true
})
```

I get the following result:

[image]

no matter what number I use the lines are always 1px thick. I've noticed that the same is true for threejs api demos page:

[image]

is this a known bug? is there any work around?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Thickness of lines using THREE.LineBasicMaterial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638883/thickness-of-lines-using-three-linebasicmaterial)

Comment: Voted to close, as it's a duplicate, but you probably didn't know what to search for. Good job providing an image. But in short: yes, it is a known defect in three.js, or rather in the underlying ANGLE-based WebGL implementation. Workarounds require either a mesh-based (https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine/blob/master/README.md) or shader based (see webgl_materials_wireframe sample) approach.

Answer (score 6):

The maximum required thickness of lines in WebGL1 is 1 so basically your browser or OS or driver has a limit of 1 for line thickness.

In WebGL2 it's even more common for the limit to be 1 because it's 1 in OpenGL 4.0+ Core Profile.

From the OpenGL 4.+ specs, section E.2.1

> ### E.2.1 Deprecated But Still Supported Features
>
> The following features are deprecated, but still present in the core profile. They may be removed from a future version of OpenGL, and are removed in a forward compatible context implementing the core profile.
>
> - Wide lines - LineWidth values greater than 1.0 will generate an INVALID_VALUE error.

While WebGL2 is based on OpenGL ES 3.0 on desktops it runs on top of OpenGL 4 or ANGLE both of which have a limit of 1. Since Firefox 51 and Chrome 56 shipped yesterday and both are using ANGLE or OpenGL 4+ on desktops that means the limit is now 1 pretty much everywhere even in WebGL1

The point of all of that is unless you only care about lines of with 1 you shouldn't use GL's line drawing to draw lines (yea, I know, sounds silly).

Instead you need to come up with some other solution.

Some links,

First a library for three.js

https://github.com/spite/THREE.MeshLine

Otherwise some articles about how to create lines

http://labs.hyperandroid.com/efficient-webgl-stroking

https://cesiumjs.org/2013/04/22/Robust-Polyline-Rendering-with-WebGL/

https://mattdesl.svbtle.com/drawing-lines-is-hard

Comment: this is why being a web developer really sucks

Comment: It's no different on native. The OS upgrades something and you're S.O.L.