# How to change AxesHelper colors in three js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using `AxesHelper`, but I want it looks different than original one. Can we change the `AxesHelper`'s material?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can change the colors of `AxesHelper` like so:

```
var axes = new THREE.AxesHelper( 10 );

//reset axes colors
var colors = axes.geometry.attributes.color;

colors.setXYZ( 0, 1, 0, 0 ); // index, R, G, B
colors.setXYZ( 1, 1, 0, 0 ); // red
colors.setXYZ( 2, 0, 1, 0 );
colors.setXYZ( 3, 0, 1, 0 ); // green
colors.setXYZ( 4, 0, 0, 1 );
colors.setXYZ( 5, 0, 0, 1 ); // blue

scene.add( axes );
```

three.js r.94

Comment: Thanks! It worked. one quick ques please. how to increase axishelper width? I want it to look thicker.

Comment: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41911520/1461008). Also see [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11349).

Comment: @WestLangley  was working with Three.js r.94 the color are not changing with the above changes

Comment: @deepakthomas Thanks. Updated post.