# How to change the thickness of GridHelper lines?

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I'm rendering a grid using Three.js (v0.86.0):

```
let grid = new THREE.GridHelper(1000, 20);
scene.add(grid);
```

The lines generated by [`GridHelper`](https://threejs.org/docs/api/helpers/GridHelper.html) seem to have a thickness of 1 pixel.

[image: grid screenshot]

I'd like to increase the thickness of lines to 3 pixels, but have no idea how to do it. I tried changing the value of `grid.geometry.getAttribute("position").itemSize` but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know if it can be done? that line of code is as arbitrary as `grid.geometry.gremlin.hamburger["price"]`. Some reading:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638883/thickness-of-lines-using-three-linebasicmaterial

Comment: In particular, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41911520/1461008) and [this](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/11349).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you can't change the line thickness on Windows.

This is because `GridHelper` uses `LineBasicMaterial` internally, and as they write in the [documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/LineBasicMaterial): "Due to limitations in the ANGLE layer, with the WebGL renderer on Windows platforms linewidth will always be 1"

Comment: According to the comment above from @WestLangley, it is actually a problem on all platforms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41911520/1461008