# Three js line thickness

Tags: three.js, line, thickness

I am using three js and need a way to draw lines that have a thickness greater that 1px. Whenever I use `LineBasicMaterial` and try to change the `lineWidth` property, nothing happens. There is already a reason related to Windows Chrome versions so I am asking if there are any good, working alternatives that can help me achieve thick lines.

Here is the material:

```
const material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
        color: "red",
        lineWidth: 20
});
```

Comment: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_lines_fat.html

Comment: This question has been asked before, with many answers here: [Thickness of lines using THREE.LineBasicMaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638883/thickness-of-lines-using-three-linebasicmaterial)

Answer (score 2):

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/materials/LineBasicMaterial.linewidth
As in the above link said : 
.linewidth : Float
Controls line thickness. Default is 1.

**Due to limitations of the OpenGL Core Profile with the WebGL renderer on most platforms linewidth will always be 1 regardless of the set value.**