# Line Width on a BoxBufferGeometry in React Three Fiber?

Tags: react-three-fiber

I am looking for a very simple example of a box with thick edge lines.

I have looked into three.meshlines, but all the examples are too complex.

I am only looking for an example in react three fiber! Can someone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thickness of lines using THREE.LineBasicMaterial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11638883/thickness-of-lines-using-three-linebasicmaterial)

Comment: Thanks! I looked into this question, a bit hard to follow. I just need to put thick edges on a box in react three fiber, do u have any example/codepen I can follow?

Comment: if you visit https://threejs.org/examples/?q=lines you can find line examples and several ones for thick lines.